# Xamarin Forms - XLabs CustomRadioButton : ItemsSource

Tags: xamarin, radio-button, xamarin.forms, itemssource, xamarin.forms.labs

I'm currently using the **CustomRadioButton** component from XLabs. I learned from the sample that you can set the text from the radio buttons by giving a string array to the ItemsSource property of the **BindableRadioGroup**.

**Example :**

```
BindableRadioGroup buttonGroup = new BindableRadioGroup();
ansPicker.ItemsSource = new[]
        {
            "Red",
            "Blue",
            "Green",
            "Yellow",
            "Orange"
        };
```

Now, I would like to now if it is possible to do the same thing with an object.

**Example :**

```
public class Person {
    private string name;
    private int age;
}
```

If I have a List of this *Person* object, can I give it directly to the ItemsSource property of the BindableRadioGroup? How do I define which attribute will be display on the CustomRadioButton?

I found this method for a ListView but in my case, I can't find the ItemTemplate property for the BindableRadioGroup :

```
var template = new DataTemplate (typeof (TextCell));
// We can set data bindings to our supplied objects.
  template.SetBinding (TextCell.TextProperty, "FullName");
  template.SetBinding (TextCell.DetailProperty, "Address");

  itemsView.ItemTemplate = template;
  itemsView.ItemsSource = new[] {
    new Person { FullName = "James Smith", Address = "404 Nowhere Street" },
    new Person { FullName = "John Doe", Address = "404 Nowhere Ave" }
  };
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`BindableRadioGroup` is actually derived from a `StackLayout` so I don't think you're going to be able to use a `DataTemplate`.

Without having tested this you could try two things. Looking at the [code](https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/blob/master/src/Forms/XLabs.Forms/Controls/RadioButton/BindableRadioGroup.cs), `Text` is set to `Item.ToString()`in `OnItemsSourceChanged`. You could define to a `ToString()` for your `person` object.

Alternatively you could handle the creation of each `CustomRadioButton` yourself, binding each property such as `Checked` and `Text` and manually add each `CustomRadioButton` to your `BindableRadioGroup`object.